# Views in CakePhp INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: php, cakephp

I have the following *Layout* (called: "MyView.ctp") in /app/view/layouts

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>
        <!-- add favicon here-->
        <!-- js -->
        <?php echo $scripts_for_layout; ?>    
     </head>

    <body> 

    </body>
</html>
```

I have the following *View* (called MyView.ctp) in /app/view

```
<?php $html->css('fup-prototype','stylesheet', array('media”=>”all' ), false); ?>
```

The following *css* file (called fup-prototype.css) in app/webroot/css/

But am getting this error:
[image: img1]

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
array('media”=>”all' )
```

you most likely meant

```
array('media'=>'all' )
```

Comment: And even then, for future reference, it's important take notice of ” vs ". When copying code, you should always check to make sure it doesn't use special characters like that.